# Bootstrap: changing dropdown menu's active link color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, colors

I am trying to change the color and background color of the active link in a boostrap's dropdown menu.

I have overriden bootstrap's @dropdownLinkColorActive and @dropdownLinkBackgroundActive  variables but this has no effet.

The css for ".navbar-inverse .nav .active > a" takes over, as seen in firebug:

```
.navbar-inverse .nav .active > a, .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a:focus {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #4D4D4F;
}

.dropdown-menu > .active > a, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: #16A170;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #17AA76, #149466);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: 0 none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Why is the .navbar-inverse class overriding the .dropdown-menu class ?

Answer (score 4):

Probably cause the dropdown is in the navbar.

This one should work

```
.dropdown-menu > .active > a, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > .active     >     a:focus {
    background-color: #16A170 !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #17AA76, #149466) !important;
    background-repeat: repeat-x !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: 0 none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assume the backgroud-color you need is #fff
write this:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a,
.dropdown-submenu:focus > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #fff);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#fff), to(#fff));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #fff);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #fff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #fff);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff', endColorstr='#fff', GradientType=0);
}
```